# node server with json rpc for angularjs website

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, json-rpc

how do I setup a server json file for node and an angularjs website as client?
My client is a website which is created with angularjs. How do I setup this to send requests to the server and get response from there?
My server is a node server. How do I setup the json file to communicate with my client?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [node-json-rpc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-json-rpc).

You can declare a method on the (node) server side like this

```
server.addMethod('myMethod', function (params, callback) {
  var error, result;
  //implementation here
  callback(error, result);
});
```

and call it on the client side (angular) like this:

```
client.call(
  {"method": "myMethod", "params": [1,2]},
  function (error, result) {
    //Handle result
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it correct that this example is for the http communication where the client is pulling and synchron?